# Поля Date и Time на вьюхе для одного поля в модели

Tags: c#

Имеется класс с полем даты:
public Class
{
        public DateTime DeliveryDateTime { get; set; }
}

На вюьхе надо отображать поля даты и времени отдельно..но чтобы при записи значения из этих 2х полей записывались в базу в одно поле...Как сделать помогите плиз..

Comment: какой вьюхи? И какое отношение база данных имеет к этой вашей "вьюхе"?

Comment: в общем у класса есть поле DeliveryDateTime .. как сделать на вьюхе 2 поля для отдельного отображения даты и времени.. но хранить эти 2 значение в одном поле (DeliveryDateTime) ?

Comment: @plastilin еще раз: 1) что за "вьюха"? 2) какое отношение эта "вьюха" имеет к базе данных?

Comment: @plastilin, что используете? winforms, wpf, asp.net, asp.net mvc? какая вьюха у вас?

Comment: asp.net mvc

Comment: ну а какое отношение представление имеет к базе данных? Собирайте в модели ваш DeliveryDateTime из отдельной даты и отдельного времени и пишите его в базу.

Comment: пример можно?? как передать в модель? извините опыта мало..от сюда такие вопросы

Comment: @plastilin если вы хотите чтобы вам помогли, то уж будьте добры, и вы нам помогите. Я вам уже несколько раз задаю простые вопросы, на которые вы почему-то избегаете отвечать. С этой вашей "вьюхой" худо-бедно разобрались. Теперь по поводу базы. Я уже в четвертый раз вас спрашиваю - какое отношение представление имеет к базе данных? Вы собрались прямо с клиента пихать данные в базу?

Comment: из вьюхи данные должны попадать в контроллер он их передат в модель. вопрос в том как в контроллер передать 2 значения (дату и время)

Answer (score 1):

Вариантов может быть несколько:

0 . Можете "собирать" дату из отдельных даты и времени на клиенте. Что-то такое:

```
var myDateTime = $('#date').val()+ ' ' + $('#time).val()
```

а затем отправлять полученное значение в контроллер и делать с ним все, что душе угодно. Привязка моделей в asp.net mvc работает вполне удовлетворительно, на сервере ваша строка будет распарсена в корректный DateTime

1. если отправка на сервер происходит не аяксом, а формой, то можете завести какой-нибудь hidden, который свяжете с формой, и менять его значение опять же через JavaScript по мере изменения поля с дайто или временем. Впрочем, это довольно муторно и не элегантно
2. можете использовать например knockout.js, который возьмет на себя всю головную боль с привязками тех или иных значений к тем или иным элементам управления, и будет обновлять их автоматически по мере изменения контролов. Это, пожалуй, самый адекватный способ
3. можете отправлять отдельно дату и отдельно время на сервер, а затем уже на сервере составлять из них общее значение. Впрочем, вероятно, вашему серверу и без этого есть чем заняться.
4. Можете завести в модели целы=х два поля,  одном из которых будете хранить дату, а в другом время, а DeliveryDateTime сделать свойством, которое будет получаться путем сложения двух вышеозначенных величин. Однако выглядит как хреновая попытка притянуть за уши MVVM туда, где его не должно быть.
5. Наиболее извращенский - создать свой тип данных, который будет хранить в отдельных полях дату и время, и уже на представлении привязывать к контролам эти два его поля. Впрочем, этот вариант - исключительно для иллюстрации плохого решения. Не стоит его использовать

Из вышеперечисленных вариантов наиболее адекватны те, где "склеивание" происходит на клиенте. Я бы на вашем месте воспользовался вариантом с knockout - эта библиотека очень удобна и не требует лишней ветвистой логики. Вот [небольшой пример](http://knockoutjs.com/examples/helloWorld.html) работы с ней.

Отображение же на представлении будет выглядеть примерно так:

```
@Html.TextBox("date", Model.DeliveryDateTime.ToString("dd MM yyyy"))
@Html.TextBox("time", Model.DeliveryDateTime.ToString("hh:mm
```